# Jquery, not sure how to capture the elements i want

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im a php developer, very little experience with javascript/jquery.

Basically i have a textbox and a link with a href. When the user "keyup"s in the textbox i want the href in the link to append the value.

However i have multiple textboxes and links that should be changed together.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="chapter_update">
            <form>
                <input class="target" type="text">
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="link" href="/index.php/cases?id=5">The link</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="chapter_update">
            <form>
                <input class="target" type="text">
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="link" href="/index.php/cases?id=5">The link</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Okay so after seeing that basic set up, lets the the user type into the first text box "23-27". Now i want this to be added to the links href. So it will be appended with "&chapter=(WHAT EVER THEY TYPE IN THE TEXT BOX)".

How can i achieve this in jquery?.

I have tried a few things, my last attempt is below:

```
<script>
    $('.target').keyup(function(){
        var currentHref = $('.link').attr("href");
        $(this).parents('tr').next('tr').closest('.link').attr("href", currentHref + $(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Any help would be great thank you.

Comment: Use `.find('.link')` instead of `.closest('.link')` in line 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were on the correct path until searching for the `.link`. To search for direct/nested children in jQuery, use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.closest('tr').next('tr').find('.link').attr('href', function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-original-href') + that.val();
    });
});
```

Also, note above we do not set the attribute with

```
$('.link').attr("href");
```

because there are many `.link` elements. We use `$(this)` in the context of the *found* `.link` element

Finally, use custom data-* attributes to preserve the original href like

```
 <a class="link" href="/index.php/cases?id=5" data-original-href="/index.php/cases?id=5">The link</a>
```

```js
$('input').keyup(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.closest('tr').next('tr').find('.link').attr('href', function() {
        return $(this).attr('data-original-href') + that.val();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <div class="chapter_update">
            <form>
                <input class="target" type="text">
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="link" href="/index.php/cases?id=5" data-original-href="/index.php/cases?id=5">The link</a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <div class="chapter_update">
            <form>
                <input class="target" type="text">
            </form>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="link" href="/index.php/cases?id=5" data-original-href="/index.php/cases?id=5">The link</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: sorry, i meant to say text box's dont know why i said texareas in the text above

Comment: @MatthewSmart, your fine :)

Comment: however you answer did not work Ammar. When i type in the first textbox it changes the bottom link not the next link in the same tr. Also i need to URL to stay how it is from the start and append &chapter=20-23. IF they type again it becomes ?chapter=20-23?chapter=20-235.

Comment: @MatthewSmart, see my updated answer and snippet. It modifies the nearest `.link` and handles not keeping on appending to the href

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what i needed. I love seeing different developers all throwing out many different way to tackle a problem. great community!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is working actually.

```
$.each($('.link'), function(){
    $(this).attr('default', $(this).attr('href'));
});
$('.target').keyup(function (e) {
    var input = $(this);
    var closestlink = input.closest('tr').next('tr').find('.link');
    var linkHref = closestlink.attr('href'); // You aren't using this actually, but just in case you need to use the current href, not the default.
    var defaultHref = closestlink.attr('default');

    closestlink.attr('href', defaultHref + input.val());
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e8uLc9nm/1/

Another option would be removing this part

```
$.each($('.link'), function(){
     $(this).attr('default', $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

And adding via HTML a `default` tag for your link or something else with the default value, this way you won't need to use jQuery to set the default value.

Comment: Best answer so far. However i need the first href for every link to be kept globaly. And when the keyup to delete the previous keyup and apend the new keyup to the href. Or else the lnik keeps getting longer and longer with the same url + 1 character from keyup

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer, it is working the way you want I think.

Comment: This works, i have already given best answer away as they just beat you too it. But it was the same concept. Thank you very much for this though!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#txt').keyup(function(e) {

    $("a").attr("href", $("a").attr("href") + String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase());

    $("div").html($("a").attr("href"));

  });

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<a href="&chapter=some_text_before_">some text for link</a>
<div>


</div>
```

Comment: Nice answer, however it needs to remove the apended section after every keyup or else if they delete and start typing again it still has the values there.